# Jacob I have loved Easo I have hated

Tags: commentaries, book-of-malachi

The prophet Malachi in Ch 1:2,3 says “...Was not Esau Jacob's brother?” declares the Lord. “Yet I have loved Jacob; but I have hated Esau...,
Here a selection is made by G-d, between two brothers. What do Rashi and other commentators say about the reason behind that choice?
I would deeply appreciate any response that would throw light on this.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Malbim

> וע"כ שהאהבה לישראל הוא רק מצד עצמותם וזה תבטל אהבת האבות שיש לעשו חלק בה ויתהפך אצל עשו לאיבה ושנאה אחר שלא הכשיר את מעשיו, ומביא ראיה ששנא את עשו ממה שאשים את הריו שממה: ‏

> The difference is because of their different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

אהבתי - הטעם בני אב אחד אחים היו עשו ויעקב ואני נשבעתי כי בריתי אקים את יצחק ואני אהבתי יעקב ונתתי לו ארץ כנען שנשבעתי לאבותיו לתת לזרעם וגרשתי עשו מארץ השם, ונתתי לו הר שעיר בעבור כבוד אביו ובעבור רשעו שמתי הריו שממה. וכן קראהו גבול רשעה והנה אתם בני יעקב הנה שבתם אל ארץ הברית:

The Ibn Ezra says it is about the fact that Yaakov is given Eretz Yisroel and Eisav is given no portion in Eretz Yisroel